# Subtract 2 days from International Network Days in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get 2 days behind the current date provided Saturday, Sunday and Holidays or not included.

Table where my holidays are stored - [DateTable[Holidays]]

I know it requires the usage of Application.NetworkDays_Intl, but I am not able to get the logic going.

Does Anyone know what is the easy way to achieve this >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function NetworkDays_Intl takes a start date and an end date and calculates the number of workdays in the range. This forces a slightly cumbersome approach:

```
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date

Dim Duration As Integer

Duration = 2
EndDate = CDate("2017-07-08")

' Pick theoretically latest start date
StartDate = DateAdd("d", -Duration + 1, EndDate)

' Step one day back until we get it right
Do While Application.NetworkDays_Intl(StartDate, EndDate) <> Duration
    StartDate = DateAdd("d", -1, StartDate)
Loop
Debug.Print StartDate
```